# Hybris application as saas in java/.net application

Tags: oauth, sap-commerce-cloud

we have a requirement of exposing the hybris application as SAAS.is there any recommended approach of loading the hybris application in any other java/.net application ?

Comment: You question not clear, please add more detail. My understanding: You can run hybris on docker. So you can prepare your solution as docker image and rapidly online them as SaaS.

Comment: It needs to be exposed  an application with its own store front in the parent .net application.The Parent application is going to act like a container for the entry points to invoke the Hybris storefront.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you should use [OCC](https://help.hybris.com/6.7.0/hcd/8c91f3a486691014b085fb11c44412ff.html).
You can find an [exemple](https://help.hybris.com/6.7.0/hcd/8bfb9f2a866910149794dc05c6a090cd.html) of implementation with AEM.

Comment: It needs to be exposed an application with its own store front in the parent .net application.The Parent application is going to act like a container for the entry points to invoke the Hybris storefront.